# Dynamic select from a table and Insert/update based on conditions after reading data from csv

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a csv file with columns as below

1) Primary keys of a random table

2) some other columns of that random table ( This no. may vary). It can have zero to n number of other columns.

Now I am given the table name. But I do not know any information about the table.

Now my job is to write a pl/sql script

1. Get the metadata of the given table and select from that table based on the primary key values in the csv file.
2. If the value in the csv file exists in the table then update the table's other columns with the values from the csv file based on the primary key.
   3.If the value in the csv file does not exists in the table then Insert all the fields with their values in the csv file.

I want to make this script dynamic so that it works for
1. Any table.

2. Any sequence of columns in the csv file.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Look into using the DBMS_SQL package. Best of luck.

Comment: This sounds like a problem that will require a different programming language, like Java.  SQL and PL/SQL can do anything *inside* a database.  But the Oracle tools for importing data, like SQL*Loader, are static and require a specific file format.

Comment: Look at the [UTL_FILE package](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS069): this can open and read a file (from a location known to Oracle) and you can then write your own PL/SQL logic to parse the records read and act accordingly.

Comment: I know how to use the UTL_FILE.FOPEN and UTL_FILE.GET_LINE to read a csv file. But my problem is requirement specific. I want to write a pl/sql script and make it dynamic so that it works for any table and its associated csv input file.Any code snippet will help.